# how to partition 1TB for ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have 2 hard drives. Windows 10 on 4TB which I am using currently. I have another 1TB hard drive where I want to install Ubuntu alongside windows. Please help me with no of required partitions and their respective sizes. Also suggest recommended partition types (EXT4 etc).

Comment: I was about to recommend reading https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apcs03.html, but this needs to be updated so badly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose the **Alongside Windows** install option, Ubuntu would be installed on the same drive as Windows.  The install process will resize the Windows partition, giving you a slider for adjusting the amount of space to specify for Ubuntu.

You can use an install option and specify the entire hard drive of your 1TB.  It will automatically partition the drive for usage.

If you decide to partition the drive yourself, then install Ubuntu on the partition of your choice.  The recommended requirements for space for Ubuntu version 18.08 is 25 GB.  That being about the minimum, having the available space, I would strongly recommend using at least twice the minimum.

Many users create a **root** partition for the install, a **home** partition for their personal space and a **data** partition for all the data they may accumulate and store over the years.  A swap partition used to be an important component, but the starting with 18.04, Ubuntu uses a swap file rather than a swap partition, so creating a swap partition is no longer necessary.

You can use **Gparted** from the Live Install media (boot the **Try Ubuntu** option) for performing the partitioning.

A partition should be the `ext4` type for Ubuntu.  The preferences for the size varies between users.  Having three partitions, **root**, **home**, and **data**, should be a educational start, using **50**, **100**, **850** respectively.

I would use the **data** partition for shared files and storage, easily available for all the users on the computer.  This would include pictures, movies, iso backups of various disk, general backups and archives, etc.  The **home** folder will be mainly for the most personal files and data, as well as configuration files.  You can use a symbolic link to the data partition to use that space as if it were in your home folder.

Comment: Thanks much. will this still be a dual boot? or do i need to go to bios everytime I want to swithc OS?

Comment: It will be a dual boot.  You only have to go to the Bios one time and specify the boot device.  As long as you specify the Ubuntu boot device, all your installed OS's will be included in the boot menu... this is automatic.  It even happens if you install Grub on your USB stick as your boot device.

Comment: how do i set up the data partition while installing Ubuntu? which device should I select for bootloader installation? 4tb (windows) or 1tb ?

Comment: @Jack You can set either for the bootloader.  Just be sure to have the one that you set for your bootloader the same as the default drive configured in your computer's bios.  Since you most likely already have `/dev/sda` ad the default in your bios, keeping this the same would make things more seamless.

Comment: how do i set up data partition that is eve accessible by windows? what will the partition type and mount point?

Comment: @Jack The answer to your new question is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76546/ubuntu-experience).  Please review and update there with other questions.  Am glad to help.